# Google Drive API - loading a doc from webViewLink for a specific user when multiple users are signed in

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm using the Google Drive API v3 to get data about a give file, specifically the `webViewLink`. I then take that webViewLink and open it, generally embedded in an iframe.

The problem I'm running into is sometimes the browser has credentials for multiple Google accounts, and I can't control which Google account credentials get used when the document is loaded.

The situation is more complicated than this, but let's just say it's on a shared computer at a school, and two different students have signed in. So one student does their work, including accessing something on Google Drive, and then goes away, leaving their account signed in. Another student comes along and accesses a shared document on Google Drive. They think they are making edits using their own google account, but the load doc is actually being edited using the credentials of the first student, even though my tool used the second student's credentials to access Google Drive and get the `webViewLink` to load the doc.

So, I know the ideal situation would be to not have a shared computer, etc. But my question in this case: is there a way to either get a user-specific `webViewLink` or append some sort of of query parameter to the `webViewLink` to coerce it to load with the second student's credentials? I want the `webViewLink` returned to reflect the user whose credentials were used in requesting it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, in a way. You can add `/u/0`, `/u/1` etc to the URL path to coerce the user to the first logged in, second logged in, but of course that assumes that you know which accounts are signed in in which order. Messing about, a large number, say `/u/999` resolves to the most recently logged in user.

Also, this works `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/user1@gmail.com/my-drive` vs `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/user2@gmail.com/my-drive`. However I don't know if the same URL syntax can be used to add the email to a webViewLink.

Note however that this is not official and could change.